# Sub CSS Classes (two sliders but need different css rules)

Tags: css, slider, styles, swiper.js

I am using Swiper.Js for my sliders on a website and need to use two sliders on the same page. My question is how do I make the CSS different for each? I can not re write all the classes for another slider as i connect the style sheets and JS from their website.

Is there some kind of subclass function for CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your sliders with different id or class so you can target your slider according them.

Comment: So Ive added a class around the slider I want different styles on. How would I reference this in the stylesheet? ive seen uses of several classes in one rule and i have also seen this '>' before.

Comment: Target your slider like

.class-1 .slider-1 { your property }
.class-2 .slider-2 { your property }

Comment: Brilliant. thanks for that. Sorry for my lack of brain.